# how to convert a boost::weak_ptr to a boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, boost-smart-ptr

i have a shared_ptr and a weak_ptr

```
typedef boost::weak_ptr<classname> classnamePtr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<x> xPtr;
```

how to convert a weak_ptr to a shared_ptr

```
shared_ptr = weak_ptr;
Xptr = classnameptr; ?????
```

Comment: did you bother to look at the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm)? It's on the first page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As already said

```
boost::shared_ptr<Type> ptr = weak_ptr.lock();
```

If you do not want an exception or simply use the cast constructor

```
boost::shared_ptr<Type> ptr(weak_ptr);
```

This will throw if the weak pointer is already deleted.

Answer (score 9):

You don't convert a `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` as that would defeat the whole purpose of using `weak_ptr` in the first place.

To obtain a `shared_ptr` from an instance of a `weak_ptr`, call `lock` on the `weak_ptr`.
Usually you would do the following:

```
weak_ptr<foo> wp = ...;

if (shared_ptr<foo> sp = wp.lock())
{
    // safe to use sp
}
```

Comment: hey idan thanx for the response

Comment: typedef boost::shared_ptr<TSmsMessage> SmsMessagePtr; inorder to avoid cyclic references im gonna change this to weak  ptr how do i do it

Comment: typedef boost::weak_ptr<classname> classnamePtr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<classname> classnameWeakPtr;

Comment: is this the way we declare a weak_ptr

Comment: well in your `shared_ptr` typedef there's the word `weak` so that might be misleading. but to give you a more complete answer you're gonna have to show more code and be more specific.

Comment: typedef boost::shared_ptr<TSmsMessage> SmsMessagePtr;
typedef boost::weak_ptr<TSmsMessage> SmsMessageWeakPtr;                  now already my code is making use of SmsMessagePtr (shared_ptr) now that to avoid cyclic references im making use of weak_ptr so shd i change al the place of shared_ptr to weak_ptr if so how to do it???

Comment: @Idan K: actually I always found this missing that a copy constructor did not exist that would call `lock` for you. I assume they meant to remind the user of what was going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

```
boost::shared_ptr<Type> ptr = weak_ptr.lock(); // weak_ptr being boost::weak_ptr<Type>
```